# My powershell script for renaming is not handling special characters

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, file-rename

I have a PowerShell script that is supposed to take a list of filenames from a txt file and rename a bunch of files in a folder using the content of the txt file.
It works great until I meet characters like é and '.
For example the string "café-m" becomes "cafÃ©-m" after running the script.

The script:

```
$names = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Desktop\locationForNames\names.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Desktop\filesToRename"
for($i = 0; $i -lt $names.Length; $i++){
    $newname = $names[$i]
    Rename-Item $files[$i].FullName -NewName $newname -Force
}
```

I have tried replacing -Path with -LiteralPath but the result remains the same.
This is my first and only experience with PowerShell and a friend helped me make it, so it's fair to say I'm a newb. Please explain as I'm five years old!
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like [encoding issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.2). What's the character encoding for `names.txt`?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to check. Does it relate to the Get-Content mehtod?
I can see that Get-Content has a parameter called -Encoding where I can choose between stuff like: "Ascii", "String", "Unicode", "UTF32" and so on.

Is that relevant? I did not specify anything so I'm assuming it's defaulting to one of those encoding types.

Should I use -Path or -LiteralPath?

Comment: I can add that the characters are properly viewed inside names.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from vonPryz I found the answer.
The encoding of the txt file needed to be changed to UTF-16 LE.
No need for -LiteralPath in my case.

To change the encoding open the txt file in notepad and choose Save As, then choose the right encoding.